# encontrar una registro comprendido entre dos fechas - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente verificar, si una fecha que estoy intentado registrar esta entre las que tengo registrada en la tabla, que es la siguiente,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOBUSINES` (
  `NOBUSINESID` int NOT NULL,
  `REPRESENTANTEID` int NOT NULL,
  `START` datetime NOT NULL,
  `END` datetime NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `NOBUSINES` (`NOBUSINESID`, `REPRESENTANTEID`, `START`, `END`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2022-03-16 08:00:00','2022-03-16 10:00:00'),
  ('2', '1', '2022-03-17 08:00:00','2022-03-18 11:00:00');
```

Al momento que estoy intentado verificar si hay un registro que este comprendida, entre el rango de fecha indicado debe lanzarme el siguiente registro,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ejecuto la consulta no lo hace y necesito ver esta parte ya que antes de insertar una hora, pero ya hay un registro que tiene de 8:00 AM del mismo dia hasta las 10:00 AM, si intento registrar un registro del mismo dia de 9:00 AM a 11:00 AM debe traerme el registro anteriormente mostrado, porque esta dentro de rango indicado, pero al realizar la consulta no me lo hace, he tratado con un BEETWEEN y tampoco me funciona,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito de su ayuda o sus consejos,

Quedo a la espera de sus comentarios,

Comment: pero por qué te debería retornar la primera fila si le estás diciendo en la variable que `END` es a las 11:00 y la fila en la tabla tiene el `END` a las 10:00?

Comment: Porque la fila `START` es a las 8:00 AM y `END` es a las 10:00 AM, pero la variable `StartDate` esta entre 9:00 AM y la `EndDate` a la 11:00, esto es porque de 8 a 10 esta reservado y si hay un registro, durante ese periodo de tiempo no puedo agregar otro registro entre 8 a 10, pero si de 10 a 11 y quiero obtener ese registro para hacer una validacion y enviarle un mensaje de que no puede agregar esta hora porque ya hay una entre este rango @Lamak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y agregar los query como texto en lugar de usar screenshots.

Ahora bien, respecto a tu duda, puedes resolverlo combinando `BETWEEN` y `OR` para comparar si la fecha/hora de inicio **o** la fecha/hora fin esta dentro del rango que le pases por parámetro.

Creamos el esquema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOBUSINES` (
  `NOBUSINESID` int NOT NULL,
  `REPRESENTANTEID` int NOT NULL,
  `START` datetime NOT NULL,
  `END` datetime NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `NOBUSINES` (`NOBUSINESID`, `REPRESENTANTEID`, `START`, `END`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2022-03-16 08:00:00','2022-03-16 10:00:00'),
  ('2', '1', '2022-03-17 08:00:00','2022-03-18 11:00:00');
```

Y ejecutamos la consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM `NOBUSINES`
WHERE `START` BETWEEN '2022-03-16 09:00:00' AND '2022-03-16 11:00:00'
OR `END` BETWEEN '2022-03-16 09:00:00' AND '2022-03-16 11:00:00';
```

Probado en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]